# Toggle div visibility based on multiple select values

Tags: jquery

I want to show some children of div#options based on multiple values of the select box.

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
<option selected="selected" value="">- Select -</option>
<option value="4">4th Option</option>
<option value="5">5th Option</option>
<option value="6">6th Option</option>
<option value="7">7th Option</option>
<option value="8">8th Option</option>
<option value="9">9th Option</option>
</select>

<div id="options">
<div class="form-item-a">content a</div>
<div class="form-item-b">content b</div>
<div class="form-item-c">content c</div>
<div class="form-item-d">content d</div>
<div class="form-item-e">content e</div>
<div class="form-item-f">content f</div>
<div class="form-item-g">content g</div>
</div>
```

No helpful classes to associate with, I am afraid.

I tried below, but only worked for a single value, while I expected to have an array of values:

```
$('#select').change(function (e) {
    // Strange, without pseudo :checked, no event triggered.
    var options = $(this).find('option:checked').val();

    // Show .form-item-a, if values 4, 5, 6
    $('.form-item-a').toggle($('option[value="4, 5, 6"]:selected',this).length > 0);

    // Show .form-item-b, if values 5, 6, 7
    $('.form-item-b').toggle($('option[value="5, 6, 7"]:selected',this).length > 0);

     // etc.
 $('.form-item-c').toggle($('option[value="8, 9"]:selected',this).length > 0);
});
```

Placing the array values here (value="4, 5, 6") is obviously wrong, but this illustrates what I am trying to achieve, because I have no idea to put them into the array jquery way. How to put the values into the array, so they are available as arguments to toggle the visibility of some divs.
Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Any hint would be very much appreciated as always.

Thanks

Comment: The pseudo selector should `:selected`. `:checked` is for checkboxes/radios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code might need optimizations but it gives you the idea.

You could maybe use data attributes:

```
<select id="select">
    <option selected="selected" value="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="4" data-showdiv='form-item-a'>4th Option</option>
    <option value="5" data-showdiv='form-item-a'>5th Option</option>
    <option value="6" data-showdiv='form-item-a'>6th Option</option>
    <option value="7" data-showdiv='form-item-b'>7th Option</option>
    <option value="8" data-showdiv='form-item-b'>8th Option</option>
    <option value="9" data-showdiv='form-item-b'>9th Option</option>
</select>

<div id="options">
    <div class="form-item-a">content a</div>
    <div class="form-item-b">content b</div>
    <div class="form-item-c">content c</div>
    <div class="form-item-d">content d</div>
    <div class="form-item-e">content e</div>
    <div class="form-item-f">content f</div>
    <div class="form-item-g">content g</div>
</div>
```

and jquery code:

```
$('#select').change(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val(),
        toShow = $this.find('option:selected').data('showdiv');

    // hide all divs
    $('#options > div').hide();

    // show the one
    $('.' + toShow).show();

});
```

Hope it helps, d.

---

To really suit your need to show more than one div by option, the data attribute solution does not work as presented.

I think you can simply go this way for your case:

```
$('#select').change(function (e) {

    // no need to get the option, val() on the select works
    var val= $(this).val();

    // no need to re-select the option for the value, you just selected it
    $('.form-item-a').toggle((val === "4" || val === "5" || val === "6"));
    $('.form-item-b').toggle((val === "5" || val === "6" || val === "7"));

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try, but is there a way to not use "data-showdiv"? The reason is the values may overlap, so I need some freedom to decide what divs belong to what values.

Comment: Of course. I find the use of the data attributes interesting because the logic code remains even if you decide that option 4 should display div.form-item-b instead of div.form-item-a afterall.

Comment: Yes, very helpful. But: <option value="4"> may need to toggle several divs, etc. They don't have a single association, I am afraid.

Comment: Indeed. This works only when you one to show one div at a time. I realized that :-)  I added another solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That array stuffs works like a charm, and gave me more freedom :) Thank you